# What am I doing wrong with my PHP text boxes piece of code?

Tags: php, forms, post, textbox

//  Hy..I have the following piece of code:

```
mysql_select_db("baza_chestionar", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT intrebari.descriere_intrebare,intrebari.nume_admin,intrebari.id_chestionar FROM intrebari WHERE intrebari.nume_admin='".$_SESSION['nume_admin']."' AND intrebari.id_chestionar='".$_SESSION['nr_chestionar']."'  ");

$i=0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $i++;
  echo $i.")&nbsp". $row['descriere_intrebare'];
  echo "<br><br>";
  echo "<form method='POST' action='selectare_raspuns.php' id='myform' >
        <input type='text' size='30' name='intrebare[]'>
        </form>     ";
  echo "<br><br>";

  }

 echo "<input type='submit' value='Salveaza raspunsuri' onclick='myform.submit()'/>";
mysql_close($con);
```

//  This select some data from a table and display it and for each data a textbox. I have another  page that takes the data from the textboxes and insert it in another table. Here is the code:

```
foreach($_POST['intrebare'] AS $textbox)
{   
    $sql="INSERT INTO raspunsuri values ('','$textbox')";
    var_dump($sql);
    if (!mysql_query($sql))
      {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "1 record added";
}
```

// But it only inserts the first value of the first text box. What am I doing wrong? I declared the name of the text box as an array an I loop thru with a foreach statement..

Answer (score 1):

You're looping the `myform` form as as well. The FORM tag should be taken out of the while loop and the submit button should be within the form tag (so you can use it without JS). Also, just print_r your POST data to confirm you have the data there.

Comment: You seem to have a firm grasp on this, could you elaborate on who this part works: <input type='text' size='30' name='intrebare[]'> Specifically with the name attribute. What does having the name as an array accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: It allows the data you post to be treated as an array. This is particularly useful when you have checkboxes and you want to act on all the checkboxes that were clicked. You could give each of them a name (wrong way) or you could just treat them as an array and then loop through them on the server side.

Comment: So in this case, each textbox text would be put into the next available index of intrebare[], from 0 to whatever the last one is?

Comment: yup. If you want you can supply that index yourself as well. so intrebare[a], intrebare[b] .... is also valid.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you use more than one form tag in your page. So only one value text box is send to your second page. You must declare the form tag before the while loop and you close the tag after your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your form tag is echoed inside the loop. Put is outside.

```
echo "<form method='POST' action='selectare_raspuns.php' id='myform' >\n";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
      $i++;
      echo $i.") ". $row['descriere_intrebare'] ."<br /><br /><input type='text' size='30' name='intrebare[]'><br /><br />";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='Salveaza raspunsuri' name="submit" />\n";
."</form>\n";
```